# How to run a Powershell function through a Python script

Tags: python-2.7, powershell, subprocess

I am trying to create a translator-type program in Python (this is 2.7, if that is important). I want to receive user input, translate it, and then print their output to the screen. That part is not difficult, but I also want to export it to a text file. I am using Powershell for that, with the *subprocess* module. The Powershell script is very short, and all it does is asks for the user to copy and paste the Python translation into an input. It then calls *New-Item* to create a file and gives it the *value* option as the Python translation.

Python code:

```
def translator:
    inquiry = raw_input("Leetspeak trans query: ") #Enter query
    inquiry = inquiry.lower() #Change all to lowercase, so that everything gets translated
    newPrint1 = "" #The new string that gets returned to them at the end
    level = raw_input("What type of 1337 do you want? 1 for basic, 2 for intermediate, \
    3 for intermediate-advanced, and 4 for ultimate.")

    if level == "1":
        from b4s1c_l33t import leetkey
    elif level == "2":
        from In73rm3d1473_1337 import leetkey
    elif level == "3": 
        from In7_4DV import leetkey
        from In7_4DV import combokey
    elif level == "4":
        from U17IM473_1337 import leetkey
        from U17IM473_1337 import combokey

    for char in inquiry:
        if char in leetkey:
            newPrint1 += leetkey[char]
        else: 
            newPrint1 += char #Checks to see if the char is in the single-char list, then appends it accordingly

    if int(level) >= 3:
        for item in combokey:
            if item in newPrint1:
                newPrint1 = newPrint1.replace(item, combokey[item])

    print newPrint1 #Print answer

    question = raw_input(r"Do you want to translate some more? Type Y or N  ") #Asks if they want to do more
    question = question.lower() #Changes it to lowercase, for sending through the if loop

    if question == "y" or question == "Y":
        translator() #If answer is yes, program calls the entire function again
    elif question != "y" and question != "n" and question != "Y" and question != "N":
        print "I didn't quite catch that."

    ps = raw_input("Would you like to export your leetness to a file? Type Y or N   ")

    if ps == "Y" or ps == "y": 
        import subprocess
        subprocess.call(["C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe", ". \"./1337Export.ps1\";", "&export"])

    else: 
       print r"0|<. 600|)|3`/3!"

translator() #calls the function once
```

Powershell script:

```
Function export(){
    $param = Read-Host("Copy-paste the translation from above here!   ")
    New-Item C:\Scripts\1337\1337ness.txt -type file -value $param
}
```

But I also know that the script was working perfectly up until I added the Powershell to it, so the problem is either in my usage of the subprocess module or in the Powershell script itself. I am a somewhat-medium-beginner at using Powershell, so any help will be greatly appreciated. Either that, or if there is a way to create the new file and write data to it in Python itself, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Prem

Note: in the Python script, the *leetkey* and *combokey* are in separate files that are imported based on the value of the variable *level*.

UPDATE: I looked at the page [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508809/run-powershell-function-from-python-script), and the *subprocess* code in the Python script is what I found in that page. It did not work, but instead threw an error saying that the *export* function does not exist, which it obviously does... in Powershell. Thanks again!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run PowerShell function from Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508809/run-powershell-function-from-python-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parameter construction is off. You want to run the following commandline in PowerShell:

```bsh
. "./1337Export.ps1"; & export
```

which basically means "dot-source (IOW import) the script `1337Export.ps1` from the current working directory, then call (`&`) the function `export`".

The cleanest way to do this is to put the statement in a scriptblock:

```bsh
&{. "./1337Export.ps1"; & export}
```

and pass that scriptblock as a single argument, so your Python statement should look like this:

```py
subprocess.call(["C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe", '-Command', '&{. "./1337Export.ps1"; & export}'])
```

Of course you need to make sure that `1337Export.ps1` actually exists in the current working directory when you execute the Python script.

Comment: Thank you so much! I could not figure out what was wrong with it. Apparently the code worked, but the 1337Export.ps1 wasn't in the working directory. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You have to do two things:

**1)** *dot source* the script (which is similar to python's import), and

**2)** *subprocess.call.*

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe", ". \"./SamplePS\";", "&export"])
```

**Note:** I have assumed that both the **.py** and **.ps1** are residing in the same directory and the name of the powershell script is *"SamplePS"* and from that script I am using the function *"export"*

Hope it helps