# Running powershell function from python not working

Tags: python, powershell

I'm trying to import a powershell script to use its function using python but the syntax I use seems to be off.

```
p = subprocess.call(["C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe", '-Command', '&{". .\powerview.ps1"; & Invoke-CustomShareFinder}'])
```

Following thses instructions : [How to run a Powershell function through a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41083296/how-to-run-a-powershell-function-through-a-python-script)

The error :

```
. .\powerview.ps1
& : The term 'Invoke-CustomShareFinder' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:32
+ &{". .\powerview.ps1"; & Invoke-CustomShareFinder}
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Invoke-CustomShareFinder:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Basically its this script but I renamed its function:
https://github.com/PowerShellEmpire/PowerTools/blob/master/PowerView/powerview.ps1

Any ideas ?

EDIT:

The function is working when manually imported and launched from powershell:

```
PS C:\Users\gcaille\Documents\my_program> . .\powerview.ps1
PS C:\Users\gcaille\Documents\my_program> Invoke-CustomShareFinder
\\server\ADMIN$         - Remote Admin
\\server\C$     - Default share
\\server\IPC$   - Remote IPC
```

Comment: Does the code (the command contents) run in PowerShell terminal/ISE?

Comment: Yes, edited question with proof

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my problem using another approach :

```
p = subprocess.Popen([r'powershell.exe',
                  '. .\powerview.ps1',
                  '; & Invoke-CustomShareFinder'])
p.communicate()
```