# Run Powershell commands from Python

Tags: python, powershell

I know related questions where already posted, but I cannot get a hang of them.

I have a Powershell-command and put it in Python in a string, say string `aa`.

How can I run command `aa` from Python. I know I should use `subprocess`, but I am not sure in what way.

Think of `aa` as `cd ../data` to get from the current folder to another folder, but also more complicated commands are possible, such as:

`docker run --rm -v $pwd\xml\:C:\xml -i LocationOfRegistry powershell /C 'cat C:\xml\*.xml | python .\core-wrap\run.py' > output.csv`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508809/run-powershell-function-from-python-script)...

Comment: What kind of "PowerShell command" are you talking about? A cmdlet? A script? What would form a "more complicated command"?

Comment: See the edited question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

process = Popen(['cd', path], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```

Comment: Are you sure this is to open a folder? I get an error stating that the file specified cannot be found, while the path is correct. And what if I want to run a command other that `cd`?

Comment: You put a different commandinstead. if you want to open a file you use `f = open(path,'r')`

Comment: Edit: Adding `Shell=True` solves the first problem.
How can I now run other command, like calling docker from Powershell?