# How to use a Python output in a powershell script?

Tags: python, powershell, office365

I started learning Python this week, and I am trying to automate adding a new user to both active directory, and on Office 365.

I have managed to add the user to AD using a client and a bot, and also use another script to generate the correct `New-MsolUser` syntax for `Powershell`.

How do I get Python to open `Powershell` and run the output of "o365command"?

Also will I need to connect to the tenant every time I do this so will I need to incorporate this into the script as well?

Happy to show the code I have if needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run PowerShell function from Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508809/run-powershell-function-from-python-script)

Answer (score 0):

If you provide the output from Python as JSON to a file, then PowerShell can import that directly. See ConvertFrom-Json ([ConvertFrom-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7.1)).

As for running PowerShell from Python, look at: [Running an outside program (executable) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811691/running-an-outside-program-executable-in-python)
It's not something I've ever tried but good luck.