# Getting the Windows uptime

Tags: c#, event-log

How can I get the uptime day by day in windows 7 for the last month?

the system sometime hibernate in the middle of day for few hours. or may be shuted-down.

My expected output is like the following:

```
Start Time |   UpTime  |
2013/12/1  |  28:31:20 |
2013/12/3  |  42:29:51 |
2013/12/7  | 128:22:17 |
```

---

**UPDATE 2013-12-15**

I found this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196452/EN-US) but I can't find any event with 6005, 6006, 6008 or 6009 in my event viewer under windows 7

---

**UPDATE 2013-12-19**
I'm looking for a C# code that helps me to read events from the windows eventlog to calculate the uptime in a specific period of time.
Quering the WMI results only to get the uptime of the current session.

Comment: There's something seriously wrong with your clock if you think it is December 5th.  Surely the core reason for the problem.  Use superuser.com to ask how to enable auditing.

Comment: This question is answered on ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/questions/159612/windows-server-last-reboot-time

Answer (score 1):

You can't get such information without additional friction. 
But you can calculate these time periods from Windows Event Log, based on Logon\Logoff events.

You can get full list of logon\logof events from  [Eventopedia](http://eventopedia.cloudapp.net/Events/?/User%20Activity/Logons/Successful%20Logons/Windows%202000-2003)

Check your system log for 528 and 538 events.

Comment: it's for windows server, what about windows 7

Answer (score 0):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11606994/642579) to a similar question that shows a way that uses PowerShell and WMI. You can transfer this to .NET and run a similar WMI query. For a tutorial on WMI and C# see this [link](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/42934-using-wmi-class-in-c#/). 
There are several other options that are listed in the other answers to the aforementioned question.